# Chef is not picking up my local cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, graphite, statsd, grafana, aws-opsworks

I am writing my first set of cookbooks to install grafana (for StatsD).

However when I do an inlcude_recipe("grafana::default"), a recipe which is not provided by my local cookbooks is picked (I am guessing from upstream).

I am using kitchen.ci to "converge" - the chef run completes successfully.

What am I missing here (or doing wrong)?

My folder structure

```
/cookbooks
|- /chef-grafana
|-- < folder structure from author of https://github.com/JonathanTron/chef-grafana - I cloned this repo >
|- /my_statsd_graphite_grafana_cookbook
|-- /recipes
|--- default.rb
|-- /attributes
|-- metadata.rb
|-- Berksfile
```

metadata.rb

```
name("my_statsd_graphite_grafana_cookbook")
version("1.0")
depends("apt")
depends("statsd")
depends("graphite")
depends("grafana")
recipe("my_statsd_graphite_grafana_cookbook", "StatsD Recipe")
```

Berksfile

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'
metadata
cookbook 'apt', git: 'git://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apt.git'
cookbook 'statsd', git: 'git://github.com/librato/statsd-cookbook.git'
cookbook 'graphite', git: 'git://github.com/hw-cookbooks/graphite.git'
cookbook "grafana", path: "../chef-grafana"
```

default.rb

```
include_recipe("apt")

# Solve some deps
install_packages = ["python-pip", "python-dev", "build-essential", "unzip"]
install_packages.each { |install_package|
  package(install_package)
}

# Include statsd recipes
include_recipe("statsd::default")
include_recipe("graphite::packages")
include_recipe("graphite::carbon")

# Include grafana recipes
include_recipe("grafana::default")
```

I even tried doing many debug logs in the cloned chef-grafana default.rb recipe, but they are never called.

What am I missing?

Thanks so much.

Comment: You can omit the `::default` and just use `include_recipe("grafana")` for the default recipes.. I would try with a fully qualified path to the cookbook instead of a relative one to ensure the problem is not from this. You may try to configure kitchen to do [verbose logging](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen#usage) too to see where it takes the cookbook from.

Comment: Thanks for the verbose tip. Will try it out.

Comment: Any update ? Maybe a log output to complete the question ?

Answer (score 0):

## EDITED

Make sure you have `name` attribute populated in `metadata.rb` and have not messed up `~/.berkshelf/config.json` and `BERKSHELF_PATH` .

Comment: Yes, every cookbook has its own Berksfile. my_statsd_graphite_grafana_cookbook also has its own Berksfile.

Comment: @Tensibai removed it.